# Python PPTX Cell alignment in the table is not working

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I am trying to add and populate a table in slide using python-pptx. But when I am trying to access each cell and change its alignment (both horizontal and vertical), nothing happens. Alignment always stays the same. What am I doing wrong here? Please help

I have tried all possible combinations of PP_ALIGN, PP_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT, MSO_ANCHOR & MSO_VERTICAL_ANCHOR. Here's my code:

```
####| Adding Table
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

table1_holder = shapes2.add_table(5,2,Inches(1),Inches(2),Inches(7),Inches(3))

#| Table Style reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/hh273476(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
tbl =  table1_holder._element.graphic.graphicData.tbl
style_id = '{9D7B26C5-4107-4FEC-AEDC-1716B250A1EF}'
tbl[0][-1].text = style_id

table1 = table1_holder.table
table1.columns[0].width = Inches(5)
table1.columns[1].width = Inches(2)
table1.first_row = True
table1.vert_banding = False
table1.horz_banding = False
# table1.alignment = PP_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
# table1.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.BOTTOM

#Adding data
#Headers

rc00 = table1.cell(0, 0).text_frame
rc00.vertical_anchor = MSO_VERTICAL_ANCHOR.BOTTOM
#rc00.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.BOTTOM
rc00.paragraphs[0].alignment = PP_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.LEFT
#rc00.paragraphs[0].alignment = PP_ALIGN.LEFT
rc00.text = "Metric"
rc00.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.name = "Optimistic Text"
rc00.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.bold = True
rc00.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.size = Pt(7)
rc00.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x00)



rc01 = table1.cell(0, 1).text_frame
rc01.vertical_anchor = MSO_VERTICAL_ANCHOR.BOTTOM
#rc01.vertical_anchor = MSO_ANCHOR.BOTTOM
rc01.paragraphs[0].alignment = PP_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
#rc01.paragraphs[0].alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
rc01.text = "Status"
rc01.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.name = "Optimistic Text"
rc01.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.bold = True
rc01.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.size = Pt(7)
rc01.paragraphs[0].runs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
```

Here's the output(s):
[cell(0,0) & cell(0,1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwjeI.png)

[cell(0,0) & cell(0,1) with there format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyTvE.png)